# how to capture HTTP packets in wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, capture, packet

I want to capture packets with some filter.
how can I capture HTTP packets in Wireshark1.12.4?
and how can I filter packets with "POST" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is filter for capturing http packets:

```
"port 80"
```

and this is filter for capturing http POST packets:

```
"port 80 and tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x504f5354"
```

Comment: Bear in mind this is not a generic solution, as http traffic can use any port (not just 80.)   (8080 being a specifically designated alternate http port,  but lots of others are commonly used)

Comment: Can someone explain exactly what the POST filtering logic is doing? 
@JeffUK This may not be generic, but the question is about capture filters, which are much more limited than display filters. If you're dealing with lots of volume, and need a capture filter to deal with it, this sort of thing can be very useful, and it one often knows what port one is interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, to capture, select your interface and press 'start capturing' then to filter, put:

```
http.request.method == "POST"
```

in the display filter.

Comment: are you sure? I checked the reference materials here http://www.askapache.com/software/sniff-http-to-debug-apache-htaccess-and-httpdconf.html#HTTP_Display_Filter_Options . it is case sensitive, did you copy the case correctly? (sorry don't have wireshark available to verify, doing this from memory :))

Comment: I found the way to capture http packets : "port 80"

Comment: but how can I capture POST packets?! :(

Comment: I can use your filter just after start capturing but not in "Capture Options" before starting capturing.

Comment: Yeah, Capture option filters are different to display filters; they're much more simplistic,  so you can filter on ports and IP addresses.  You could filter based on the protocol here but it's a LOT easier to just use display filters.